# Does -nexclude work when using JiBX as the CXF databining?

Tags: wsdl, cxf, jibx

I am trying to get CXF (2.7.7) to use JiBX (1.2.5) for databinding. The documentation is a bit sketchy, but there have been reports of success with it. One problem is that CXF does not pass configuration to the JiBX code generator, so if you need to do something that requires customization, such as mapping Joda DateTime to XML Schema date, you need to be able to tell CXF to ignore specific namespaces and then handle those with a separate call to JiBX.

The examples I have seen use the CXF -nexclude flag for this purpose, as in

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generateSources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${generated-sources.dir}/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlRoot>${wsdl.dir}</wsdlRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${wsdl.dir}/GetCounters.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <dataBinding>jibx</dataBinding>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>http://www.example.com/counters/</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have tried both inline and imported versions of the namespace but the -nexclude flag does not appear to work with JiBX. One option might be to let JiBX do the whole WSDL without invoking the CXF plugin, but apparently this creates problems in the generated service code. An ugly workaround might be to let JiBX regenerate the code for just the classes in this namespace, overwriting the code created by CXF.

Can the -nexclude flag be made to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem while using jaxb. This worked for me:

move the extraargs out of the wsdlOption section and into the defaultOptions section.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${cfx.codegen.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <defaultOptions>
                <extraargs>
                    <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>http://domain.company.org/v1/schema1</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
                    <extraarg>http://domain.company.org/v1/schema2</extraarg>
                </extraargs>
            </defaultOptions>
            <wsdlOptions>
                <wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlArtifact>
                        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
                        <artifactId>application-contract</artifactId>
                        <version>${contract.version}</version>
                        <type>wsdl</type>
                    </wsdlArtifact>
                </wsdlOption>
            </wsdlOptions>
            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```